# Viewing full access mailboxes in OWA

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app, mailbox

I'm running Exchange 2010 and I give full access permissions to the HR mailbox to John.  John only accesses his mailbox through OWA; he doesn't even have Outlook on his Mac.  How does John view the HR mailbox through OWA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upper right corner of OWA, click the user name drop down, type the username for the mailbox you want to open, and click the Open button.